# Can typescript impelement singleton pattern using enum?

Tags: typescript, singleton

I've read about impelementaion of singleton pattern using enum in Java and known that this kind of impelementation is easy to write and thread safe. Does enum have same mechanism in Typescript? Because so far almost every impelementation of singleton in Typescript I've read about is to use a static property and a getter function which checks if the property has value or not:

```
export class Demo {
    private static instance: Demo;
    private constructor () {
        // do something
    };
    public static getInstance() {
        if (!this.instance) {
            this.instance = new Demo();
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
}
```

Clearly this impelementaion is not thread-safe.

Comment: Java enums are special which makes "enum" a bit of a misnomer. They are full classes. In TS and almost all other languages that have it, an enum is a simple mapping of label to a simple value (some times just an int, TS allows numbers and strings) that ensures uniqueness if both. E.g. `MyEnum.A` is a single thing and the value is also unique for `MyEnum`. Yet if `A = 1` you can also just use `1` in its place. Or `MyOtherEnum.B` which might also happen to resolve to `1`. That's the case in C++, for example.

Comment: "*Clearly this impelementaion is not thread-safe.*" why does it have to be? Are you solving [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? JS execution is not multithreaded by nature. You have to explicitly opt-in. And even then, why would you really need thread-safe singletons? You can leverage modules for that. Not to mention DI solutions. What is the purpose of 1. Implementing a singleton by yourself. 2. Trying to do it via an enum (which cannot work).

Comment: Hi, thanks for diving into the problems. Actually I'm using a framework called `egg.ts` who has mechanism like `cluster` in `node.js`. When I use this framework to launch chrome instance on a multi-core platform, I want to ensure that there's exactly one instance to the maximum. This is acutually an IPC problem, and I'm finding an elegant solution for that.

Comment: An XY problem then. With the Y being enums in TS.

Comment: Now I'm very grateful to you for pointing out the fallacy I falls into when asking questions... I'm going to close this problem and refine my skill of asking questions.